# Execute another installer silently within your Nsis installer

Tags: nsis, silent-installer

I am trying to execute ffdshow.exe silently within my nsis installer but ffdshow doesnt seem to work with my method but MatroskaSplitter.exe and other installers have run silently with the same method.

`File "..\Prerequisites\ffdshow_rev4515_20130612_clsid.exe"

  ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\ffdshow_rev4515_20130612_clsid.exe" /S'`

Comment: Do you have any warning/error in the `makensis.exe` output log during compilation? Do you have any error at runtime? if you start the same command manualy, does it work?

Comment: @Seki Thanks for your effort, no errors though but I have got an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure ffdshow uses NSIS?

It [looks to me](http://sourceforge.net/p/ffdshow-tryout/code/4523/tree/trunk/bin/distrib/) like they are using Inno so you could try  `/silent` or `/sp- /silent /norestart`.